# PIL: make image transparent on a percent scale

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How can I make `watermark` image transparent? For example, 60% transparent. I have tried with `putalpha` but seems that it's doesn't work as expected

```
from PIL import Image


temp_image = Image.open('test1.jpg')
watermark = Image.open('watermark.png')

x, y = temp_image.size

image_with_watermark = Image.new('RGBA', (x, y), (0, 0, 0, 0))
image_with_watermark.paste(temp_image, (0, 0))
image_with_watermark.paste(watermark, (0, 0), mask=watermark)
image_with_watermark.show()
```

EDIT:

ok, this works, need to figure out how to set it up using %

```
from PIL import Image


temp_image = Image.open('test1.jpg')
watermark = Image.open('watermark.png')

x, y = temp_image.size

watermask = watermark.convert("L").point(lambda x: min(x, 50))
watermark.putalpha(watermask)

image_with_watermark = Image.new('RGBA', (x, y), (0, 0, 0, 0))
image_with_watermark.paste(temp_image, (0, 0))
image_with_watermark.paste(watermark, (0, 0), mask=watermark)
image_with_watermark.show()
```

meh, quality of the watermark is very low after:

```
watermask = watermark.convert("L").point(lambda x: min(x, 50))
watermark.putalpha(watermask)
```

What is the best way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a solution that will work for both RGB and RGBA watermark images:

```
from PIL import Image

TRANSPARENCY = 65       # percentage

temp_image = Image.open('test1.jpg')
watermark = Image.open('watermark.png')    

if watermark.mode!='RGBA':
    alpha = Image.new('L', watermark.size, 255)
    watermark.putalpha(alpha)

paste_mask = watermark.split()[3].point(lambda i: i * TRANSPARENCY / 100.)
temp_image.paste(watermark, (0,0), mask=paste_mask)
temp_image.save('res.png')
```

Sample image (author - [Neil Howard](https://www.flickr.com/photos/neilsingapore/432143033/)):

[image: Singapore]

Sample watermark (the background is transparent):

[image: Stack Overflow caption]

Sample result:

[image: Singapore + Stack Overflow watermark]